# Elasticsearch configuration settings

Tags: elasticsearch

What does the setting "discovery.zen.ping.multicast.group" mean in elasticsearch?
Documentation is not clear enough on this. I suppose this might be of some help to me for setting up a nodeClient.

I am trying to create a java node client without having to resort to unicast discovery methods as I want my nodeClient to switch seamlessly when the master goes down, and my nodeClient with the following setting has not been able to detect master so far.

```
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
         .put("cluster.name",ESProperties.getInstance().getCacheClusterName())
            .put("http.enabled", "true")
            .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", "true")
            .put("discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout","60s")
            .build();

    Client client = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(settings)
            .client(true).node().client();
```

Comment: You can find more details here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/150

Answer (score 0):

In a multicast network configuration, receivers join a multicast group which defines the hosts to which sent messages will be delivered. `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.group` allows you to set the address of the multicast group that the node should join.